# How to set several route params in routerLink (Angular 2)

Tags: angular, routes

I want to set several params to my route.

```
<a [routerLink]=" ['user',user.name,user.id]"></a>
```

With my routes :

```
routes = [
  { path: 'user/:user_name/:user_id', component:UserComponent}
]
```

Url is changing but i'm redirected to my 404 page.

Any ideas ?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you need to add a slash before 'user' (e.g. `['/user',user.name,user.id]`).

Comment: Works fine @drbishop

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is construct a link in a function. Then in your anchor tag create a `(click)=functionName()` whenever the anchor is clicked.

```
let link = ['/somelocation', this.param, this.param];
    this.router.navigate(link);

<a (click)="thefunctionwheretheaboveishappening()">Some Description</a>
```